# Hibernate, Could not parse configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

I am new to Hibernate .... i tried this code but i got `Could not parse configuration: NewFile.cfg.xml` (name of .cfg.xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

  <session-factory>
    <!-- connection to oracle -->
    <propertyname="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
</property>                 
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">system</property>

    <!-- autocommit -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>

    <!-- to display sql query generated while running program  -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

    <!-- for jdbc transaction -->
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.
JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

    <!-- mapping file -->
    <mapping resource="Mapping.hbm.xml"/>       
  </session-factory>
```

Comment: `</session-factory>>`, extra `>`  in the end

Comment: Be sure that you gave us the exact xml that you used, because the tag of hibernate-configuration is missing

Answer (score 1):

The end tag for `<hibernate-configuration>` is missing:

```
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: is it throwing any exception? can you update your question with the error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver </property>
```

Your opening tag  not match the ending tag.